# How can I access the image data from a FITS file?

Tags: python, astropy, fits

how can I access the image subsample from a FITS file?

I could not tell where exactly the data is in the file! The file headers show that it's in the second header and that it is of dimension 1024*1024! But when I try to access the second header I don't get the image array, instead I get a "nonetype" file! I believe there is something wrong am doing here!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
import cv2
headerList=fits.open('AIA20100630_0000_0211.fits')
#Load table data as image data
#imgData = headerList[1].data 
imgData = headerList[0].data 

hdu=headerList[1]
print('shape :',hdu.shape) #shape is 1024*1024

#show image
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(imgData)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though you access the second HDU here:

```
hdu=headerList[1]
```

you don't display the `data` from that HDU, but you chose `imgData` from the first HDU:

```
imgData = headerList[0].data
... 
plt.imshow(imgData)
```

The fix would be simply to display `hdu.data`:

```
plt.imshow(hdu.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `fits.open()`, you might want to look into using `fits.getheader('img.fits')` and `fits.getdata('img.fits')`. These methods are generally more convinient if all you need is the header or the image data.

In your case

```
from astropy.io import fits
imgData = fits.getdata('AIA20100630_0000_0211.fits', 1)
```

should load the image data directly without going through the hdu.

Comment: "These methods are faster than opening the entire fits file if all you need is the header or the image data."  I mean, it's not "faster" time-wise, it's just a shortcut for `hdul = fits.open(filename); data = hdul[0].data` (or `hdul[1].data` if the first HDU is empty as common for some formats).  This is fine for very basic use and often convenient, but one should still learn the full object-oriented API for anything more sophisticated.